# Pagination on scrolling to bottom of window with ajax in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I got some code online from a link where pagination on an array was done with lots of records.
Example.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <title>PHP Array Pagination</title>
  <style>
  <!--
   body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
   }
   hr {
    border: 1px #ccc;
    border-style: none none solid none;
    margin: 20px 0;
   }
   a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
   }
   a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   a.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .numbers {
    line-height: 20px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
   }
  //-->
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>PHP Array Pagination</h1>
    <hr  />
      <?php

        ini_set('display_errors','On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        // Include the pagination class
        include 'pagination.class.php';

        // some example data
        foreach (range(1, 200) as $value) {
          $products[] = array(
            'Product' => 'Product '.$value,
            'Price' => rand(100, 1000),
          );
        }

        // If we have an array with items
        if (count($products)) {
          // Create the pagination object
          $pagination = new pagination($products, (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1), 15);
          // Decide if the first and last links should show
          $pagination->setShowFirstAndLast(false);
          // You can overwrite the default seperator
          $pagination->setMainSeperator(' | ');
          // Parse through the pagination class
          $productPages = $pagination->getResults();
          // If we have items 
          if (count($productPages) != 0) {
            // Create the page numbers
            echo $pageNumbers = '<div class="numbers">'.$pagination->getLinks($_GET).'</div>';
            // Loop through all the items in the array
            foreach ($productPages as $productArray) {
              // Show the information about the item
              echo '<p><b>'.$productArray['Product'].'</b> &nbsp; &pound;'.$productArray['Price'].'</p>';
            }
            // print out the page numbers beneath the results
            echo $pageNumbers;
          }
        }
      ?>
      <hr />
      <p><a href="http://www.lotsofcode.com/php/projects/php-array-pagination" target="_blank">PHP Array Pagination</a> provided by <a href="http://www.lotsofcode.com/" target="_blank">Lots of Code</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

pagination.class.php

```
<?php

  /************************************************************\
  *
  *   PHP Array Pagination Copyright 2007 - Derek Harvey
  *   www.lotsofcode.com
  *
  *   This file is part of PHP Array Pagination .
  *
  *   PHP Array Pagination is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
  *   (at your option) any later version.
  *
  *   PHP Array Pagination is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  *   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  *   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  *   GNU General Public License for more details.
  *
  *   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  *   along with PHP Array Pagination ; if not, write to the Free Software
  *   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
  *
  \************************************************************/

  class pagination
  {

    /**
     * Properties array
     * @var array   
     * @access private 
     */
    private $_properties = array();

    /**
     * Default configurations
     * @var array  
     * @access public 
     */
    public $_defaults = array(
      'page' => 1,
      'perPage' => 10 
    );

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param array $array   Array of results to be paginated
     * @param int   $curPage The current page integer that should used
     * @param int   $perPage The amount of items that should be show per page
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function __construct($array, $curPage = null, $perPage = null)
    {
      $this->array   = $array;
      $this->curPage = ($curPage == null ? $this->defaults['page']    : $curPage);
      $this->perPage = ($perPage == null ? $this->defaults['perPage'] : $perPage);
    }

    /**
     * Global setter
     * 
     * Utilises the properties array
     * 
     * @param string $name  The name of the property to set
     * @param string $value The value that the property is assigned
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function __set($name, $value) 
    { 
      $this->_properties[$name] = $value;
    } 

    /**
     * Global getter
     * 
     * Takes a param from the properties array if it exists
     * 
     * @param string $name The name of the property to get
     * @return mixed Either the property from the internal
     * properties array or false if isn't set
     * @access public  
     */
    public function __get($name)
    {
      if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_properties)) {
        return $this->_properties[$name];
      }
      return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set the show first and last configuration
     * 
     * This will enable the "<< first" and "last >>" style
     * links
     * 
     * @param boolean $showFirstAndLast True to show, false to hide.
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function setShowFirstAndLast($showFirstAndLast)
    {
        $this->_showFirstAndLast = $showFirstAndLast;
    }

    /**
     * Set the main seperator character
     * 
     * By default this will implode an empty string
     * 
     * @param string $mainSeperator The seperator between the page numbers
     * @return void    
     * @access public  
     */
    public function setMainSeperator($mainSeperator)
    {
      $this->mainSeperator = $mainSeperator;
    }

    /**
     * Get the result portion from the provided array 
     * 
     * @return array Reduced array with correct calculated offset 
     * @access public 
     */
    public function getResults()
    {
      // Assign the page variable
      if (empty($this->curPage) !== false) {
        $this->page = $this->curPage; // using the get method
      } else {
        $this->page = 1; // if we don't have a page number then assume we are on the first page
      }

      // Take the length of the array
      $this->length = count($this->array);

      // Get the number of pages
      $this->pages = ceil($this->length / $this->perPage);

      // Calculate the starting point 
      $this->start = ceil(($this->page - 1) * $this->perPage);

      // return the portion of results
      return array_slice($this->array, $this->start, $this->perPage);
    }

    /**
     * Get the html links for the generated page offset
     * 
     * @param array $params A list of parameters (probably get/post) to
     * pass around with each request
     * @return mixed  Return description (if any) ...
     * @access public 
     */
    public function getLinks($params = array())
    {
      // Initiate the links array
      $plinks = array();
      $links = array();
      $slinks = array();

      // Concatenate the get variables to add to the page numbering string
      $queryUrl = '';
      if (!empty($params) === true) {
        unset($params['page']);
        $queryUrl = '&amp;'.http_build_query($params);
      }

      // If we have more then one pages
      if (($this->pages) > 1) {
        // Assign the 'previous page' link into the array if we are not on the first page
        if ($this->page != 1) {
          if ($this->_showFirstAndLast) {
            $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page=1'.$queryUrl.'">&laquo;&laquo; First </a> ';
          }
          $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page - 1).$queryUrl.'">&laquo; Prev</a> ';
        }

        // Assign all the page numbers & links to the array
        for ($j = 1; $j < ($this->pages + 1); $j++) {
          if ($this->page == $j) {
            $links[] = ' <a class="selected">'.$j.'</a> '; // If we are on the same page as the current item
          } else {
            $links[] = ' <a href="?page='.$j.$queryUrl.'">'.$j.'</a> '; // add the link to the array
          }
        }

        // Assign the 'next page' if we are not on the last page
        if ($this->page < $this->pages) {
          $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryUrl.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';
          if ($this->_showFirstAndLast) {
            $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->pages).$queryUrl.'"> Last &raquo;&raquo; </a> ';
          }
        }

        // Push the array into a string using any some glue
        return implode(' ', $plinks).implode($this->mainSeperator, $links).implode(' ', $slinks);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

there are lot of records in the array in example.php file i.e.from 1-200.There is a file which is included in example.php ,which is pagination.class.php,in which pagination logic is provided.
I need the pagination to be done on scrolling to bottom of window.Like when ever you scroll down to bottom,next page records should be displayed with ajax call.

Like in this code.there will be number of pages link will be given.On click of them,next page records will be displayed.I need that similar thing while we scroll to bottom with ajax.

Please guide me on how to do this....

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax calls to load you further data when every time you are at bottom position, e.g

```
if (($(window).innerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop()) >= $("body").height()) {
//make ajax calls to load you data 
}
```